# Which one is not cardinality of $HK$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ and $K$ be two subgroups of $G.$ If both $H$ and $K$ have 12 elements, which of the following numbers cannot be the cardinality of the set $HK=\{hk: h\in H, k\in K\}$?

(a) 72

(b) 60

(c) 48

(d) 36

Suppose $HK$ is subgroup of $G$. Then using $|HK|=\dfrac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$, we get possible values of $|H\cap K|$ is 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12. In the options, I conclude possible 
 values of $|HK|$ is 72, 48, 36. Hence |HK|=60 is not possible. But here $HK$ may not be group, in that case i get trouble, please help me.

Comment: do you think that formula works only when $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$??

Comment: @S. Pitchan Murugan: You don't have to assume `HK` is a subgroup? Do you?

Answer (score 3):

Generally for a group $G$ and arbitrary subgroups $H,~K$, we don't have $HK\le G$. It happens, for example, when $HK=KH$. Here, as I see, there is no assumption consdering $HK\le G$ so your choice would be $60$. And you got it before.